# How to read email content of a multi part in HTML instead of text in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, html-email

I have a requirement in which I have to read the email content in HTML format, but I am getting in simple text. How can I get the content in HTML?

I have used this code:

```
public String getTextFromMessage(Message message) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    String result = "";
    if (message.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
        result = message.getContent().toString();
    } else if (message.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();
        result = getTextFromMimeMultipart(mimeMultipart);
    }
    return result;
}

public String getTextFromMimeMultipart(
        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart)  throws MessagingException, IOException{
    String result = "";
    int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result+="\n\n";
        BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
        if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            result = result + "\n" + bodyPart.getContent();
            break; // without break same text appears twice in my tests
        } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {
            String html = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
            result = result + "\n" + org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(html).text();
        } else if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart){
            result = result + getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart)bodyPart.getContent());
            
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**The output of the code is on Debug**

```
_ ____ ____From: Mohammad Rahmat Ullah <mohammedrahmathullah@iqratechnology.com> __Sent: Tuesday, August 9, 2022 3:14 PM__To: sidraansari@iqratechnologygulf.com__Cc: sabashaikh@iqratechnology.com; mohdsalmankhan@iqratechnology.com; noorullahkhan@iqratechnologygulf.com__Subject: FW: Screenshot 2022-08-08 at 16.33.02____ ____Dear Sidra,____ ____Please do the same and send me.. Visit 2013 sharepoint for older records.____ ____Portal.abaninvestment.com – 2013 Sharepoint____ ____ ____Best Regards,____Mohammed Rahmath____SharePoint Consultant________Plot No. T-17, Software Technology Park, Beside____Wockhardt Pharma, Opp. Garware Stadium, MIDC____Chikalthana, Aurangabad 431007, Maharashtra, India____ <http://www.iqratechnology.com/> www.iqratechnology.com____ ____ ____ ____From: Tariq Afzal Ehtesham [mailto:Tariq.Afzal@abaninvestment.com] __Sent: 09 August 2022 12:26 PM__To: Mohammad Rahmat Ullah <mohammedrahmathullah@iqratechnology.com <mailto:mohammedrahmathullah@iqratechnology.com> >; sabashaikh@iqratechnology.com <mailto:sabashaikh@iqratechnology.com> ; IT Service Desk <it.servicedesk@abaninvestment.com <mailto:it.servicedesk@abaninvestment.com> >__Subject: FW: Screenshot 2022-08-08 at 16.33.02____ ____ ____Dear Rahmath,____ ____Kindly provide the report for GCGOi as requested below in yellow highlight.____ ____Regards,____ ____ ____ ______ <http://www.abaninvestment.com> __ABAN INVESTMENT__Ghobash Group Operating Companies________ <https://www.linkedin.com/company/aban-investment> ____                    ____WWW.ABANINVESTMENT.COM <http://WWW.ABANINVESTMENT.COM> ______ ____TARIQ AFZAL EHTESHAM__Manager - Business Solutions__M:+971 55 4722597 | T: +971 4 5961800 | Ext: 5207__PO Box:125848, Makeen Building, Airport Road, Dubai, UAE______ <http://www.abaninvestment.com> ____ ______This e-mail is private and confidential. If received in error, please delete immediately. Sender does not accept any legal responsibility for the contents of this e-mail and/or its attachments.____From: Jerilyn Dente __Sent: Tuesday, August 9, 2022 10:48 AM__To: Tariq Afzal Ehtesham <Tariq.Afzal@abaninvestment.com <mailto:Tariq.Afzal@abaninvestment.com> >__Cc: Banan T. Alkilani <Banan.Alkilani@gcg.ae <mailto:Banan.Alkilani@gcg.ae> >; Kasinathan Kathiresan <Kasinathan.Kathiresan@gcg.ae <mailto:Kasinathan.Kathiresan@gcg.ae> >; Digi Ana Caguindagan <Digi.Caguindagan@gcg.ae <mailto:Digi.Caguindagan@gcg.ae> >__Subject: RE: Screenshot 2022-08-08 at 16.33.02____ ____ ____Dear Tariq, ____We need you kind assistance. ____We have upcoming ISO audit and we need below reports to be presented first to GM.____*    How many new CAF in 2020/2021 __*    How many total new customer in 2020/2021____ ____ ____ ____ ______ <https://www.gcg.ae> __A Ghobash Group Company______ <http://www.mps-uae.com/> ________ <https://www.linkedin.com/company/gulf-commercial-group_2> ____ <https://www.facebook.com/GCG.ES> ____ <https://twitter.com/GCG_ES> ____ <https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChwPaZduB6una81a9YosfJQ> ____        ____WWW.MPS-UAE.COM <http://WWW.MPS-UAE.COM> ____WWW.GCG.AE <http://WWW.GCG.AE> ____ ______ ____JERILYN DENTE__Sales Coordinator__M:+971 55 5027498 | T: +971 2 2014999 | Ext: 7400__PO Box:47257, Madinat Zayed Tower, 12th Floor, Sultan Bin Zayed the First Street, Abu Dhabi, UAE______ <https://www.gcg.ae/uaepass/digitalsignature> ____ ____From: Kasinathan Kathiresan __Sent: Monday, August 8, 2022 4:58 PM__To: Jerilyn Dente__Cc: Digi Ana Caguindagan__Subject: RE: Screenshot 2022-08-08 at 16.33.02____ ____ ____This has to be collected from IT ____ ____ ____ ______ <https://www.gcg.ae> __A Ghobash Group Company______ <http://www.mps-uae.com/> ________ <https://www.linkedin.com/company/gulf-commercial-group_2> ____ <https://www.facebook.com/GCG.ES> ____ <https://twitter.com/GCG_ES> ____ <https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChwPaZduB6una81a9YosfJQ> ____        ____WWW.MPS-UAE.COM <http://WWW.MPS-UAE.COM> ____WWW.GCG.AE <http://WWW.GCG.AE> ____ ______ ____KASINATHAN KATHIRESAN__Credit Control Supervisor__M:+971 50 7363878 | T: +971 4 5281000 | Ext: 5435__PO Box:25940, Makeen Building, Airport Road, Dubai, UAE______ <https://www.gcg.ae/uaepass/digitalsignature> ____ ____From: Jerilyn Dente __Sent: Monday, August 8, 2022 4:52 PM__To: Kasinathan Kathiresan__Cc: Digi Ana Caguindagan__Subject: FW: Screenshot 2022-08-08 at 16.33.02____ ____ ____Dear Sir, ____Please share the number of new customers for year 2020 & 2021____ ____ ____ ______ <https://www.gcg.ae> __A Ghobash Group Company______ <http://www.mps-uae.com/> ________ <https://www.linkedin.com/company/gulf-commercial-group_2> ____ <https://www.facebook.com/GCG.ES> ____ <https://twitter.com/GCG_ES> ____ <https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChwPaZduB6una81a9YosfJQ> ____        ____WWW.MPS-UAE.COM <http://WWW.MPS-UAE.COM> ____WWW.GCG.AE <http://WWW.GCG.AE> ____ ______ ____JERILYN DENTE__Sales Coordinator__M:+971 55 5027498 | T: +971 2 2014999 | Ext: 7400__PO Box:47257, Madinat Zayed Tower, 12th Floor, Sultan Bin Zayed the First Street, Abu Dhabi, UAE______ <https://www.gcg.ae/uaepass/digitalsignature> ____ ____From: Banan T. Alkilani __Sent: Monday, August 8, 2022 4:34 PM__To: Jerilyn Dente; Digi Ana Caguindagan__Subject: Screenshot 2022-08-08 at 16.33.02____ ____ ____Hi Jeri &Digi,____ ____Can you please help getting me the info for 2020 and 2021 for new customers achieved to target. Also the number of new machines sold in 2020 and 2021. This is for the iso audit this week. Thanks ________ ______ <https://www.gcg.ae> __A`enter code here` Ghobash Group Company______ <http://www.mps-uae.com/> ________ <https://www.linkedin.com/company/gulf-commercial-group_2> ____ <https://www.facebook.com/GCG.ES> ____ <https://twitter.com/GCG_ES>`enter code here` ____ <https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChwPaZduB6una81a9YosfJQ> `enter code here`____        ____WWW.MPS-UAE.COM <http://WWW.MPS-UAE.COM> ____WWW.GCG.AE <http://WWW.GCG.AE> ____ ______ ____BANAN T. ALKILANI__Enterprise Division Sales Manager – UAE__M:+971 50 2077878 | T: +971 2 2014999 | Ext: 7402__PO Box:47257, Madinat Zayed Tower, 12th Floor, Sultan Bin Zayed the First Street, Abu Dhabi, UAE______ <https://www.gcg.ae/uaepass/digitalsignature> ____ ____
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including a *small* sample email, expected and actual result for that sample email.

Comment: Hi Please visit to this url here I have uoloaded actual image of Email and output chich I am getting by this code                 ** https://sakhan141-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/iqratechnology_sakhan141_onmicrosoft_com/Ep0hAsJ-k85JqzybR8kPgToBF_odZCPm4MgWJV7MERYEcg?e=K6mxdr**

Comment: I'm not asking how the email looks, I'm asking for the actual source of the email message (e.g. as written out by `MimeMessage.writeTo(OutputStream)`). And please don't use screenshots of textual output, post that text as code formatted text in the question itself.

Comment: I can not send all the data on comment due to fixed size

Comment: You should [edit] your questions with additions, not put them in comments. However, to be clear, the source of the email is far more important for this question than the output (and without the source of the email, that output is largely meaningless).

Answer (score 0):

the **break** is culprit for you.
I saw the comment that result gets repeated and got the hint.

this will work for you -

```
public String getTextFromMimeMultipart(
    MimeMultipart mimeMultipart)  throws MessagingException, IOException{
String result = "";
int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    result+="\n\n";
    BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
    if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
        /*
        result = result + "\n" + bodyPart.getContent();
        break; 
        */ 
         // without break same text appears twice in my tests
    } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {
        String html = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
        //html has all the html tags for you
        result = result + "\n" + org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(html).text();
    } else if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart){
        result = result + getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart)bodyPart.getContent());
        
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer has been downvoted ! in a mutlipart element, jakarta has two elements : one plain text and one html. that answer worked for me